# Data is not saving to MongoDB using the Mongoose findOneAndUpdate Function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

I am using Mongoose to interact with a MongoDB database.

I am using this for discord bots.

I am attempting to change the Boolean `activated` to `true` in the database if the user has the role.

(The code is below)

There is no error when I try and run the function, just nothing happens and the change is not effected in the database. 
The database is connected and working, and the user has full permissions.

```js
let role = call.message.guild.roles.get('702210416012689478')

            if(!call.message.member.roles.has(role.id))
                return;

            call.client.botLoginData.find( {clientID: call.args[0] }, (err, docs) => {
                if(docs.length === 0)
                    return call.message.channel.send(`Couldn't find a client with that ID.`);

                call.client.botLoginData.findOneAndUpdate( { clientID: call.args[0]}, { activated: true });
                call.message.channel.send(`I have successfully updated that bot. Please allow up to 10 mins to propagate, and then restart the bot.`)
            }).catch(error => {
                call.message.channel.send(error)
            })
```

I am new to Mongoose/Mongo so if I'm doing something wrong please let me know

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `const query = { 
 clientID: call.args[0]
};
const update = {
 $set: {
  activated: true
 }
};
// Return updated document
const options = {
 new: true
};
call.client.botLoginData.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, (err, doc) => {
 all.message.channel.send('I have successfully updated that bot. Please allow up to 10 mins to propagate, and then restart the bot.');
});` Re-write to this

Comment: @KunalMukherjee this worked, but all these steps are required each time to update one piece of data? I don't think Mongo is right for me

Comment: No you can update any number of fields you want

Comment: @KunalMukherjee No I mean is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: Define simpler ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Like **one** line, not three. I don't get why mongo makes everything so difficult -_-

Comment: Its the way mongoose module has been written, cant do nothing on that

Comment: My main question is, why can't I just type all this in and it works...

Comment: Why do I have to put it into variables

Comment: its optional, better suited for readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KunalMukherjee responded, the answer to this question is below

```js
const query = { clientID: call.args[0] }; 
const update = { $set: { activated: true } }; // Return updated document 
const options = { new: true }; 
call.client.botLoginData.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, (err, doc) => { all.message.channel.send('I have successfully updated that bot. Please allow up to 10 mins to propagate, and then restart the bot.'); });
```

If anybody has any other suggestions please let me know!
Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add $set with the update object like this:

```
call.client.botLoginData.findOneAndUpdate( { clientID: call.args[0]}, {$set:{ activated: true }}, {new:true});
```

To know more about $set check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

Comment: Added that, same thing nothing happening. No change reflected in the database

Comment: Edited the answer check that out with new: true it gives updated document.

Comment: Nope, still not saving 
I checked the permissions for the user and it has Atlas admin so i'm super confused. There is still no error or change in the data,

Comment: @thetechguy61705 if the other one is working I don't get it why this one didn't work. Any idea about it?

Comment: No idea lol. I feel like mongoose pick's and chooses what it likes to do sometimes.